# Store Javascript Data to PHP on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

How can I store this javascript data to a php variable on the same page. This is what I've tried.

```
index.php
```

PHP

```
//Receiving Data
$ajax_data = $_POST['data'];
echo $ajax_data;
```

JS

```
    var fname = "Mike";
    var form = {"first_name":fname};

    person = JSON.stringify(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: ({
            data: person
        }),
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your question gives the impression that you did not realize that the pages sent to a browser are multiplied by as many Internet users who visit this initial page, it is the same for the variables.

Comment: is there any other way to pass a js data and store to a php variable rather than using ajax?

Comment: the other way is sending a <form>, but it implies a new page load. You are talking about a client(JS) <-> server (php) relationship...

Comment: can you give me an idea how to do it

Comment: shure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store data through JavaScript cookie and get through PHP

```
<script>
var fname = "Mike";
document.cookie = 'first_name=' + fname; </script>  

<?php echo $_COOKIE['first_name'];
?>
```